# How to save an app's information permanently on the phone?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Currently I'm working on app which allows user to use promotion code to get free stuff. The promo code can be used only once for every device. So even if user uninstalls the app and installs it again, he or she cannot use the code again to get free stuff.

However, my problem is I need to implement this on the client's side (i.e., on the phone itself). Apparently SharedPreferences cannot solve this issue, but saving some file on external storage seems quite fragile to me. Is there any good solution to the above problem?

Comment: save it on a server

Comment: Doing it only on client side is not much recommended. User can lose the phone, factory reset it, or many more tragedies can force the user to wipe everything on it. So best way to achieve what you want to is to use Google or FB login and using those credentials, store the purchase information on your server.

Comment: One of your choice is to force them to input login information. In that way you can allow/disallow some feature base on the account credentials.

Comment: Saving on server is the best option.

Comment: Can you not use "android:allowBackup="true" in the manifest ? This would have your preferences saved even when the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Both iOS & Android apps run within a sandboxed environment and do not let you create or read files out of the environment. This means that you cannot do this. The only way you can achieve this is by reading some unique identifier from the device and storing this info on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

please use webservice and save user information in server 
user_id
user_password
user_promocode
and etc.

please apply webservice on your application to solve your problem.